# How to display sky sphere?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to position sky sphere in 3D space right where camera is.

I set up camera as follows:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    // Ignore the passed-in GL10 interface, and use the GLES20
    // class's static methods instead.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 1000);
}

...
Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -5, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
...
```

Sphere has a diameter of 100 units and it's center is in (0;0;0).

The method to draw a sphere:

```
private void drawSphere() {
    //Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    mTriangleVerticesSphere.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVerticesSphere);
    mTriangleVerticesSphere.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVerticesSphere);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);

    Matrix.setRotateM(mMMatrix, 0, jitterX, 1.0f, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mMMatrix, 0, angleYaw + jitterY, 0, 1.0f, 0);
    Matrix.scaleM(mMMatrix, 0, 0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0, mMMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numPolysSphere);
}
```

This code displays a sphere. Backface culling is disabled, and I can see both sides of sphere (texture has transparent parts).
In order to display sphere right in the camera position I try to move camera. But if I uncomment `Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)` in the beginning of `drawSphere()` it doesn't display anything. May be it has something to do with clipping planes?
Please give an example how to position the sphere correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I figured out how to do it.
1. Look at correct angle.
3. Draw sky sphere.
2. Clear Z-buffer.
3. Reposition camera.
4. Draw the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think your more looking to do something like

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mvMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

if I'm not wrong opengl doesn't know which way its looking at

your asking too look for (0,0,0) towards (0,0,0) while oriented towards (0,1.0,0)

Comment: This makes sense. Actually, this way I set up camera to draw other objects in scene, this sets up camera to look to (0,0,0) from atop.
I've also tried `Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 1, 0)` but to no avail.